# Toad Autocomplete Dropdown

Tags: oracle, toad

When I put an alias into a `,(case when  a.X then a.Y end ) AS XY` Modifying the a. doesn't work at all. I am running 12.6 for toad. Does anyone know how to get the dropdown to populate always?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It won't populate always. You've encountered a shortcoming that has been discussed ad nauseam on the official Toad forums if you care to search there for detailed explanation.

Toad's Code Insight uses its parser to digest your SQL and extract from it table references, etc. If the parser cannot make sense of your code then it cannot detect table references. When using Code Insight, SQL is often times incomplete since you are actively working on constructing it. The parser can overcome a lot of hurdles with respect to incomplete code, but not all of them. Your example is one of the common examples where the parser cannot overcome your incomplete CASE statement to locate the table references in your FROM clause.

This problem has been documented and logged extensively in the bug tracker as part of a larger syntax recovery feature of the parser. There are no estimates on when it will be resolved.